# How is the @encode compiler directive implemented in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, c-preprocessor, encode, implementation

Can anyone explain how @encode works to extract the datatype elements present in a given object, struct, or datatype into a type definition to be used as a class descriptor for instantiation?

Or maybe a pointer to some resources for learning about the implementation of new preprocessor directives?

Comment: I'm thinking its just a function-type macro that somehow parses and stringifies what is passed to it

Comment: Just curious, how does the `@encode` relate to the C language (which doesn't have this keyword)?  I suggest removing the 'c' tag.

Comment: `@encode` is not a preprocessor directive, it relies on type information such as the size of types, something that the preprocessor is not aware of.

Comment: @Thomas I'm trying to do the equivalent of Objective-C's @encode in ANSI C. So the c tag is relevant.

Comment: @dreamlax I assumed the same but how does it realize the datatype construction of a struct? If you do sizeof(struct aStruct) only the size of the full struct is returned how would you determine all the data elements that make up the struct?

Comment: @dreamlax The runtime reference you linked to in your answer states it as such... (Is there a difference between compiler directive and preprocessor directive?)

"To assist the runtime system, the compiler encodes the return and argument types for each method in a character string and associates the string with the method selector. The coding scheme it uses is also useful in other contexts and so is made publicly available with the @encode() COMPILER DIRECTIVE."

Comment: A compiler directive and a preprocessor directive are two entirely different things. A preprocessor directive tells the preprocessor what to do, whereas a compiler directive tells the compiler what to do.

Comment: I think perhaps it's best to deepen your understanding of how a compiler generally works, before trying to understand what specific parts of a compiler do.

Comment: @dreamlax makes sense; I though they were all called compiler directives only some did something with the preprocessor specifically. But I think we're getting way off track from the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasing of the original question may have been unclear and I think that my mentioning of a possible implementation involving the preprocessor caused the conversation to turn toward the subtleties of how compilers work rather than the intended question.

Please reference this question, which I believe is much more clear as to what I'm trying to learn:
[How would I implement something similar to the Objective-C @encode() compiler directive in ANSI C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255637/how-would-i-implement-something-similar-to-the-objective-c-encode-compiler-dir)

Comment: It can't be done in the preprocessor because the preprocessor is completely unaware of any type information.

Answer (score 5):

The `@encode` directive parses the provided type and generates a constant string based on that type. The encoding of all C primitive types (including signed and unsigned versions) and the Objective-C `id` and `SEL` types all have single-character encodings, these can be found in `<objc/runtime.h>`. More complicated types such as `struct`s and arrays have larger encodings.

More information is available in the [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/ObjCRuntimeGuide.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: Thanks for your help but I know WHAT it does. I'm interested in HOW it does it.

Comment: Once the source has been parsed into an ASTs, the `@encode` method probably traverses the tree and inspects the individual types and generates the string from that.

Comment: The way I understand it is that at compile-time, Type Descriptors are generated using the @encode directive with the contents of each class's @interface header. These type descriptors are stored inside the binary and the .ctors section instantiates each class object at run-time using the __attribute__((constructors)) function.

Comment: So how can you introspect an opaque struct object if it is not a full-fledged object yet?

Comment: @Anderson: you can't. The encoding of an incomplete `struct` is also incomplete.

Comment: Also, what has `@encode` got to do with interface headers? Or constructors?

Comment: My overall purpose of this question and my previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219501/how-does-the-objective-c-runtime-instantiate-the-root-metaclass-and-other-class-d is to gain knowledge in how Objective-C uses the interface header to create the metaclass and class objects which must be available at runtime in order to instantiate objects.

Comment: I'm following http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf as a guide to implementing a basic ooc implementation. Rather than hard code every class description manually, I'm interested in how Objective-C does it (I've been told it uses @encode to build Type Descriptors at compile-time) to get an idea of how I could do it myself.

Comment: Objects are not required... This works... how does it do it?
('struct test
{
    int ti ;
    char tc ;
} ;
char * encodedstruct = @encode(struct test) ;
printf("%s", encodedstruct ) ;')

Comment: It's done at compile time *by the compiler*. The compiler is fully aware of each type, its size, and its signedness. You cannot implement something like this outside the compiler unless you create a static analyser to perform the same task.