# When objc runtime itself loads? Who calls it to load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

Method "**+ (void)load**" is called before **main()** , **runtime** will load all class and methods in memory before program starts, so which is the REAL entry point of an iOS app?And who and when runtime loads itself?

-----**edit**----
found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219501/how-does-the-objective-c-runtime-instantiate-the-root-metaclass-and-other-class)

Comment: The runtime doesn't "load itself". The OS (in particular, the dynamic loader/linker) calls dynamic library entry functions ("constructors") when a particular library is loaded into an executable.

Answer (score 1):

@H2CO3 gave really a hint, here's source code in objc runtime, I think this is where runtime starts to load, called by libSystem:

```
   /*
    * _objc_init  
    * Bootstrap initialization. Registers our image notifier with dyld.  
    * Old ABI: called by dyld as a library initializer  
    * New ABI: called by libSystem BEFORE library initialization time
    */

#if !__OBJC2__
 static __attribute__((constructor))
#endif
void _objc_init(void)
{
    static bool initialized = false;
    if (initialized) return;
    initialized = true;

    // fixme defer initialization until an objc-using image is found?
    environ_init();
    tls_init();
    lock_init();
    exception_init();

    // Register for unmap first, in case some +load unmaps something
    _dyld_register_func_for_remove_image(&unmap_image);
    dyld_register_image_state_change_handler(dyld_image_state_bound,
                                             1/*batch*/, &map_images);
    dyld_register_image_state_change_handler(dyld_image_state_dependents_initialized, 0/*not batch*/, &load_images);
}
```

share a link about con/de structors:http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the Mike Ash's article, [Objective-C Class Loading and Initialization](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html). You could use +initialize method instead of +load.

> An interesting feature of +load is that it's special-cased by the runtime to be invoked in categories which implement it as well as the main class. This means that if you implement +load in a class and in a category on that class, both will be called. This probably goes against everything you know about how categories work, but that's because +load is not a normal method. This feature means that +load is an excellent place to do evil things like method swizzling.
>
> The +initialize method is much nicer for most setup tasks, because it runs lazily and in a nice environment. You can do pretty much anything you want from here, as long as it doesn't need to happen until some external entity messages your class.

Comment: This question is exactly what confused me after reading Mike Ash's page, I want to figure out what happened before +load, just digging in , not in an application situation. :)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/

This WWDC session covers what you need to know, from reading Mach O files to making fix-ups in shared libraries to calling `+load` methods bottom-up on all Objective-C classes to `main()`.

Basically everything starts with `exec()` call, then `dyld` loads dynamic stuff and notifies Objective-C runtime.